# Uninitialized string offset notice when using one to five variable variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to extract up to five values from an array and place them in a msql query as such:

```
$frontpage_hot_list_data = array(); 

while (@$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_frontpage_hot_list)) {
    $frontpage_hot_list_data[] = $row['id']; 
}

$sql_frontpage_hot_down = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE 
id !='$frontpage_hot_list_data[0]' AND id !='$frontpage_hot_list_data[1]' AND
id !='$frontpage_hot_list_data[2]' AND id !='$frontpage_hot_list_data[3]' AND 
id !='$frontpage_hot_list_data[4]' AND thumbnail_large=0 AND popular=1 AND 
popular_datetime > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_onlineNowTm' AND 
views > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_views' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4");
```

The problem here appears to be when I have less than five values, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   D:\Hosting\8847501\html\scripts\timeframes.php on line 298
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   D:\Hosting\8847501\html\scripts\timeframes.php on line 299
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in
>   D:\Hosting\8847501\html\scripts\timeframes.php on line 300
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in
>   D:\Hosting\8847501\html\scripts\timeframes.php on line 301

Any idea how to solve this problem? Maybe placing in the query only the exact number of variables? Im lost...

Comment: After your while-loop, do `var_dump($frontpage_hot_list_data);` and post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create a comma-separated list of your IDs, then put this newly created list into a MySQL [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) expression (**UPDATE**: now I see that you're using `!=` in your query, so let's make it `NOT IN`).

```
$list = implode(',', $frontpage_hot_list_data);
$sql_frontpage_hot_down = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE 
id NOT IN ($list) AND thumbnail_large=0 AND popular=1 AND 
popular_datetime > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_onlineNowTm' AND 
views > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_views' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4");
```

**Important note**: I assumed here that your ids are numeric, so `implode()` would produce something like `1,5,133,31`. If they are strings, then you have to wrap them in apostrophes first using `array_map()` for example.

Also, if you expect that the array can be empty, you can add another condition that will omit the whole `id NOT IN () AND` part when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no $sql_frontpage_hot_list result, because array $frontpage_hot_list_data[] does not contain any of results

I would do following:

```
$frontpage_hot_list_data = array(); 

while (@$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_frontpage_hot_list)) {
    $frontpage_hot_list_data[] = $row['id']; 
}

if(count($frontpage_hot_list_data)) 
{
    $frontpage_ids_str = implode($frontpage_hot_list_data, ',');
    $sql_frontpage_hot_down = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE 
           id not in (".$frontpage_ids_str.") AND thumbnail_large=0 AND popular=1 AND 
           popular_datetime > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_onlineNowTm' AND 
           views > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_views' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4");
}
else
{  
    $sql_frontpage_hot_down = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE
           thumbnail_large=0 AND popular=1 AND 
           popular_datetime > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_onlineNowTm' AND 
           views > '$frontpage_hot_hot_three_views' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4");
}
```

So if we have $frontpage_hot_list_data we exclude them, if not then we ignore them.

Comment: I think it's quite unnecessary to duplicate the whole query when only a small part changes. Also, using `empty()` instead of `count()` would be more practical, not that it's a big performance issue, but sounds more logical. You don't want to know the number of elements, only if the array has any.